# Collections break

Tags: java, collections, comparable

From this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html)

> Name objects are immutable. All other things being equal, immutable
>   types are the way to go, especially for objects that will be used as
>   elements in Sets or as keys in Maps. These collections will break if
>   you modify their elements or keys while they're in the collection.
>   How do we know that the class "Name" is immutable? (class name visible in the link above mentioned)

What do they actually mean with "the collections will break if you modify their elements?"

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because with mutable classes, you can change the properties based which they are organized/ordered in the Collections, and the holder class would not know about it.

Think that you could do:

```
 public class Name implements Comparable<Name> {

    private String firstname = null
    // getters and setters

    public int compareTo(Name name) {
       // Compare based in firstName
    }
 }
```

And then:

```
 Name name1 = new Name("John");
 Name name2 = new Name("Mike");
 SortedSet<Name> set = new TreeSet<Name>();
 set.add(name1);
 set.add(name2);
 name1.setFirstName("Ralph");
```

Now, is `set` ordered or is it not?

In a similar way, changes that affect the `hashCode` of the instance break `HashMap` and similars, because the first that does these classes when inserting/retrieving objects is to use a specific `bucket` based in that value.

Comment: I think the key thing to mention here is that the statement only holds for properties that attribute to the equals, hascode and compareTo methods.  Other properties can be changed without breaking the collections.  The text snipped in the question is inaccurate.

Comment: @JoeriHendrickx If you define a `setter` for any property, then you run the risk that someone will use it in a custom `Comparator` to order a collection. So, you cannot say in a general way that "it is enough that only attributes that affect `compareTo/equals/hashCode` are not allowed to change".

Comment: indeed, you are correct.  But in all fairness, that's not such a common case :)  Saying that all elements in a collection should be immutable would be too broad nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

What they mean is, lookups based on object will be failed.

For example:

```
mylist.get(myObject);
```

will fail because the object reference you have will be different (due to modifications) from the one you are using to do `get(...)` call.

Comment: In fact for a `List` I would expect it to work (unless it is a sorted one).

Answer (score 1):

`HashSet` and `HashMap` rely on the contract for `equals()` and `hashCode` described in the javadoc for [`java.lang.Object`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html). That means that for two objects being equal accorrding to `equals()` the calculated `hashCode()` must also be equal.

If the `hashCode()` for a object in a `Set` or `Map` changes during the time the object is in the `Set` or `Map` the implementation will not find the object as it is saved in the bucket for the old `hashCode()`.

Therefore changing the `hashCode()` while an object is in a `Set` or `Map` is a really bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs on `Map`

> Note: great care must be exercised if mutable objects are used as map keys. The behavior of a map is not specified if the value of an object is changed in a manner that affects equals comparisons while the object is a key in the map. A special case of this prohibition is that it is not permissible for a map to contain itself as a key. While it is permissible for a map to contain itself as a value, extreme caution is advised: the equals and hashCode methods are no longer well defined on such a map.

From the docks on `Set`

> Note: Great care must be exercised if mutable objects are used as set elements. The behavior of a set is not specified if the value of an object is changed in a manner that affects equals comparisons while the object is an element in the set. A special case of this prohibition is that it is not permissible for a set to contain itself as an element.

Lookups are done with `.equals` on the keys, if the keys are mutable the lookup will fail.